# Run jQuery Functions After AngularJS Loaded Views and Included Partials

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using both AngularJS (v1.6.4) and jQuery (v2.1.4) in my web application. I included static `html` files using `ng-include`. So my `index.html` is like that:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
        <div class="content-page">
            <div ng-view></div>
            <div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-datatables-editable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#datatable-editable").DataTable();
    </script>
</body>
```

As you see above I have 3 include files and 1 view. I used datatable in angular view. And I want to initialize it in my `index.html` file with `$("#datatable-editable").DataTable();` But it doesn't work. When I write html elements directly to the page instead of including, it works fine. Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: Here is an example that might help. http://jsfiddle.net/TNy3w/2/

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible with jQuery?

Comment: Maybe if you produced a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Using a tool like codepen, would help providing a solution.